# Cloudfront: Do the files in my origin bucket need to be publicly readable

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I currently serve files on S3 that are private. I would like to serve files via Cloudfront but I keep getting an AccessDenied error. I have tried multiple combinations

1. With and without Cloud front key pairs
2. With and without AWS access keys

But nothing works. Do the files on my S3 bucket need to be publicly readable and then I just restrict access to them via Cloudfront by setting bucket policies?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is no *inherent* connection between S3 and CloudFront. From the perspective of S3, CloudFront is just another "user" trying to access the content. Therefore, the S3 bucket has to give permission to CloudFront to access the content. Keep in mind that there is no way to set permissions on the CloudFront distribution so your content will be publicly available that way.